LDA Error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms")
everyone. I can't understand why is giving me an error. Later on, the code was working with no errors. Packages are: quanteda, quanteda.texmodels, quanteda.textstats, quanteda.textplots, newsmap, readtext, spcyr, ggplot2, seededlda, stringr, dplyr, tidytext, knitr, stringr, igraph, topicmodes.
tmod_lda \<- textmodel_lda(dfm_selected_unico, k = 10)
terms(tmod_lda, 10)


Error in x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component nor attribute") :
no terms component nor attribute
5.
stop("no terms component nor attribute")
4.
x$terms %||% attr(x, "terms") %||% stop("no terms component nor attribute")
3.
terms.default(tmod_lda, 10)
2.
terms(tmod_lda, 10)
1.
terms(tmod_lda, 10)

Now I am using
lda <- LDA(dfm_selected_unico, k = 10) terms(lda, 10)
It is working, but I can't understand why not with tmod. The results from both encodings are quite different attending the corpus

tmod_lda may not be a textmodel_lda object. Check class(tmod_lda).

There is no function quanteda.textmodel::textmodel_lda(). Recommend you use the stm package for topic modelling.
